# Unix timestamp question, different times

Tags: unix-timestamp

I am working with Unix timestamps, but I get a different time on my Android phone and my computer than the time given on http://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php

The time difference is one hour (give or take a few seconds probably, didn't ever design an extremely accurate test).

I thought that the Unix time was the same everywhere on earth (or perhaps the universe, but that brings up questions of frames of reference and velocities that I don't even want to think about).

Basically my question is, what is going on here?  I get the time on the Android device using Date date = new Date(); long now = date.getTime(); (I account for this having milliseconds btw) and I connect through putty to a linux server and the time is the same (obtained by date +%s).  It's just the website that disagrees on the time, and since I don't know too too much about Unix timestamps and the site looks legit I wonder how this happened.

ps. I live in Saskatchewan, which doesn't observe daylight savings, but I don't see how that would really factor in.  Does the website read the time from my computer maybe?

pps.  sorry for rambling

Comment: I change the time on my computer and the website stays the same, so unless it caches the time (which doesn't make much sense) it must be reading it from a server, and I still have no idea why the times disagree.

Answer (score 6):

That web site displays the wrong time.

Comment: Really?  The first result from googling "current unix time" is wrong?  That's surprising.

Comment: Thanks, looks like other websites agree that he is wrong.  I didn't quite understant what that meant, I just assumed I was ignorant.  Looks like he was the wrong one.  Shame that his site is so easy to find on google.

Comment: also when he says switching from 32 to 64 bit systems will by the stamp a "bit" more time... isn't it 32 bits more?  I get it's wordplay, but the double meaning is wrong!